# When can I unpersist my RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, rdd

I have a method that gets called several times. This method looks like the following:

```
def separateGoodAndBad(myRDD: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
    val newRDD = myRDD.map(......)  //do stuff
    newRDD.cache  //newRDD has 2 actions performed on it

    val badRDD = newRDD.filter(row => row.contains("bad"))
    badRDD.count

    val goodRDD = newRDD.filter(row => row.contains("good"))
    goodRDD.count

    newRDD.unpersist // I am unpersisting because this method gets called several times

    goodRDD
}
```

Like I said, I want to unpersist `newRDD` because the method gets called several times and I don't want 4 copies of different cached `newRDDs`. Here is a code sample:

```
val firstRDD = separateGoodAndBad(originalRDD)
val firstRDDTransformed = doStuffToFirstRDD(firstRDD)

val secondRDD = separateGoodAndBad(firstRDDTransformed)
val secondRDDTransformed = doStuffToSecondRDD(secondRDD)

val thirdRDD = separateGoodAndBad(secondRDDTransformed)
val thirdRDDTransformed = doStuffToThirdRDD(thirdRDD)
```

However, `secondRDD` and `thirdRDD` are taking MUCH longer now that I added the unpersist (see above in `separateGoodAndBad()`. It seems that they are having to recompute `newRDD`.

When can I unpersist `newRDD` so that it never has to get recomputed?

Comment: have you checked on spark UI to check whether which task is the bottleneck (is taking large time)?

Comment: @vatsalmevada It is taking a long time because it has to execute the whole spark application up to that point. Those counts are my first spark "actions".  What I'm confused about is why it has to recompute everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to cache `goodRDD` also as it is computed once when you do `goodRDD.count` and it will be recomputed again when you perform some action on that RDD inside `doStuffToFirstRDD` method.

```
    def separateGoodAndBad(myRDD: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
        val newRDD = myRDD.map(......)  //do stuff
        newRDD.cache  //newRDD has 2 actions performed on it

        val badRDD = newRDD.filter(row => row.contains("bad"))
        badRDD.count

        val goodRDD = newRDD.filter(row => row.contains("good"))
        goodRDD.cache    // this will cache goodRDD to avoid recomputing in next call
        goodRDD.count

        newRDD.unpersist // I am unpersisting because this method gets called several times

        goodRDD
    }
```

Then you can unpersist them outside the function call something like this:

```
val firstRDD = separateGoodAndBad(originalRDD)
val firstRDDTransformed = doStuffToFirstRDD(firstRDD)

val secondRDD = separateGoodAndBad(firstRDDTransformed)
firstRDD .unpersist  //as your secondRDD will be cached by above `separateGoodAndBad` call
val secondRDDTransformed = doStuffToSecondRDD(secondRDD)

val thirdRDD = separateGoodAndBad(secondRDDTransformed)
secondRDD.unpersist  //as your thirdRDD will be cached by above `separateGoodAndBad` call
val thirdRDDTransformed = doStuffToThirdRDD(thirdRDD)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I actually was testing this exact solution when you answered the question!